# ASP.NET MVC JSON Entity Framework - Saving data

Tags: javascript, sql, json, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have an asp.net MVC3 application, trying to save data to MS SQL table (Entity Framework).
Here is the table:

```
public class CasesProgress
    {
        public virtual long ID { get; set; }
        public virtual long Learner_ID { get; set; }
        public virtual long Course_ID { get; set; }
        public virtual long StudyCase_ID { get; set; }
        public virtual long CaseList_ID { get; set; }
        public virtual bool Viewed { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult StoreProgress(long Learner_ID, long Course_ID, long StudyCase_ID, long CaseList_ID)
    {
        CasesProgress casesprogress = new CasesProgress();
        casesprogress.Learner_ID = Learner_ID;
        casesprogress.Course_ID = Course_ID;
        casesprogress.StudyCase_ID = StudyCase_ID;
        casesprogress.CaseList_ID = CaseList_ID;
        casesprogress.Viewed = true;
        db.CasesProgresses.AddObject(casesprogress);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
```

and here is my Javascript:

```
   function StoreProgress1() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/StoreProgress',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                LearnerID: "211",
                Course_ID: "6",
                StudyCase_ID: "19",
                CaseList_ID: "2"
            },
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.success);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
```

I get error message without even going to the breakpoint I have in the controller.  Any idea, I am new to this.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you are creating such a strange API? Why not to pass json object as method parameter ?

Comment: I am new to programming, do you mean just pass the Data object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in this line:

contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

I removed it and it worked.
Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 3):

Try change:

```
LearnerID: "211"
```

To (as in model):

```
Learner_ID: "211"
```

Comment: @user373721 Your controller is named as model? I am taking about `CaseProgress`

Comment: @user373721 Also I can't find `Viewed` parameter in action. Please, show error text.

Comment: Good points, I moved the action to Home controller, and removed Viewed from the javascript, and added it to the action.  Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0):

In addition to answers above, check that you have `[HttpPost]` attribute applied to your action.

Comment: Thanks, the [HttpPost] was there.